# Increasing spacing between sibling nodes in a tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I am drawing a tree with this command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[S [a]  [S [S [a] [S  [$\varepsilon$ ]] [b] ] [S [a] [S  [$\varepsilon$ ]] [b] ] ]   [b] ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

What I want to happen is that the "a" at the second level is the leftmost node with regards to all other nodes. Also "b" in the second level should be the rightmost node with regards to all other nodes.

Comment: Welcome. Please provide a full compatible minimal working example(MWE): https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look to http://ctan.space-pro.be/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/forest/forest-doc.pdf at page 10. You can use `s sep=20mm`.

> option s, control the distance between the (node) anchors of a node
>   and its parent.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[S,s sep=20mm, [a]  [S [S [a] [S  [$\varepsilon$ ]] [b] ] [S [a] [S  [$\varepsilon$ ]] [b] ] ]   [b] ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This will work (+1), but hard-coding the distance is not the most robust solution ....

Answer (score 5):

Note that the root node is at level 0. Judging from the answer you accepted, I'm going to assume that you meant level 1 rather than level 2 by 'the second level'.

The best way to achieve this is probably to use `fit=band` for the children of the root node i.e. those at level 1. This avoids the need to hard code any increased spread between the first level nodes: if more content is added to the tree, Forest will automatically increase the separation to keep the vertical space under the first and last child at level 1 free, since these have no children.

By default, Forest uses `fit=tight`. `fit=rectangle` and `fit=band` are alternatives. `fit=band` prevents anything other than the node's own descendants from encroaching on the vertical space beneath it (in a North-South growing tree).

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  [S, for children={fit=band} [a]  [S [S [a] [S  [$\varepsilon$ ]] [b] ] [S [a] [S  [$\varepsilon$ ]] [b] ] ]   [b] ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: different fit]

Comment: You are right, your solution is much better. Nice answer (+1). Thanks.

Comment: @Bobyandbob There is so much in the Forest manual .... `fit` is useful to know about ;).